# Natural Sentence and Unnatural Sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> I think that since Tom is a student, he cannot buy expensive meat.

> I don't think that Tom can buy expensive meat since he is a student.

> Since Tom is a student, I don't think that he can buy expensive meat.

Which is more natural?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the first sentence is more natural when you're in a talk or conversation. I have lived in English speaking countries for many years and people there usually say

> "I think that", *break*, "since Tom is a student, he cannot buy expensive meat".

In terms of writing, the last 2 sentences feels equally natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the sentence you place at the front depends on which words you want to lay stress on.

The first is saying that this is *your* opinion. The second could be a reply to someone who has suggested that Tom should cook some rump steak. The third is pointing out that Tom is a student, not a well-paid professional like someone else.